# C# Replace default textbox in DataGridView with a Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I’m still pretty new to C# but I’m working on a WinForms application that pulls data from an Access database. I’m currently working on a form that loads the contents from a table into a DataGridView dynamically using a DataAdapter and DataSet.

So far, the form is working as expected. Currently, to add a new record, you have to type data into each cell in a row. What I want to do is replace a couple columns (textbox) with a combobox. In other words, instead of manually entering the data, have a dropdown combobox and select the entry from a list. I also want to generate the combobox data members from SQL but if that’s too much, I can just manually code each item.

I can add a combobox to the datagridview at run time but that’s not what I’m trying to do. And since the columns are being created at run time via code, I’m not sure how to modify a column following that method.

So, for example, I want to replace the textbox cells for “Rating” with a combobox members such as “R”, “PG-13”, “PG”, etc.

```
public partial class frmBulkInsert : Form
{
    OleDbConnection conn;
    OleDbDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;
    OleDbCommandBuilder cmdbl;


    public frmBulkInsert()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmBulkInsert_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Load all records from the table into the datagridview.
        try
        {
            dataConnectionSettings();              
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,   MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void ConnectToDatabase()
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data  Source=C:\Users\ronniejones.JONES\Documents\Access Projects\Movie_2013.mdb";
    }

    private void btnUpdateRecords_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //DataSet changes = (ds).GetChanges();

            cmdbl = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
            //da.Update(ds, "Movie_2013");
            int numRows = da.Update(ds, "Movie_2013");
            MessageBox.Show(numRows + " Record(s) Updated", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,  MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

private void dataConnectionSettings()
    {
        //DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cboColumn;
        conn = new OleDbConnection();
        ConnectToDatabase();
        conn.Open();
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Title, [Minutes], Rating, Category,     Format, Actor1, Actor2, Actor3, Actor4, [Status] FROM [Movies] ORDER BY ID", conn);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Movie_2013");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Once a column is created you can't change its type. You can achieve your goal in two ways.

1. As you have already mentioned, create the required columns, add it to the grid and bind the data. If you set the `DataPropertyName` property of your column then when your data is bound that data column will get bound to your grid column. The DataGridView will generate other columns automatically. Bind a second datasource to the comboboxcolumn itself.
2. Modify your database such that the list is provided by the database and binding will automatically create comboboxcolumn.

Comment: Ok, since I'm trying to do this dynamically using code, I've pretty much tried your step 2 and I get close but not what I want.

Comment: I did as the first suggestion stated and it worked perfectly! Added new created DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, move them to the expected positions and hide textbox columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do something like this:

Once you have assigned the datasource to your gridview which is your table coming from the query:

```
   DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboBoxCell1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
   ComboBoxCell1.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" });
   this.dataGridView1[0, 2] = ComboBoxCell1;

   DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboBoxCell2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
   ComboBoxCell2.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" });
   this.dataGridView1[1, 2] = ComboBoxCell2;

   DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboBoxCell3 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
   ComboBoxCell3.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" });
   this.dataGridView1[2, 2] = ComboBoxCell3;
```

where `this.dataGridView1[int, int]` is the [column, row] of your grid, so you can count how many rows does your datatable has and `dt.Rows.Count + 1` will be the Row value in the [column, Row]

Hope this is what you were looking for and this helps

Comment: First let me apologize. I'm new to StackOverflow and I thought I would receive an email informing me that there was a response. Sorry!

Comment: So - Using this method would require that I list each row (1247 rows) and add the cell. I would definitely need to use the DataGridViewComboboxColumn method to get it to do what I intended. Unfortunately, this approach wouldn't work for me. But thank you for your input and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Maybe it helps to someone.

```
public class MyData
{
    private static int counter = 0;
    public int ID { get; } = counter++;
    public string Name { private set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }
    public List<string> Values { get; } = new List<string>();

    public MyData()
    {
        Name = "myData_obj_" + ID;
        Description = "my custom data object no. " + ID;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            Values.Add("extra data " + ID + "-" + i);
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<MyData> DataList { private set; get; }

    public Form1()
    {
        PrepareData(20);
        InitializeComponent();
        ConnectDataGrid();
    }

    private void ConnectDataGrid()
    {
        DataGridViewColumn colId = new DataGridViewColumn
        {
            Name = "ID",
            HeaderText = "Object ID",
            CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(),
            ReadOnly = true                
        };

        DataGridViewColumn colName = new DataGridViewColumn
        {
            Name = "Name",
            HeaderText = "Object Name",
            CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(),
            ReadOnly = true
        };

        DataGridViewColumn colDescription = new DataGridViewColumn
        {
            Name = "Description",
            HeaderText = "Object Description",
            CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
        };

        DataGridViewColumn colValues = new DataGridViewColumn
        {
            Name = "Values",
            HeaderText = "Object additional values",
            CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(),
            DataPropertyName=null
        };

        dgv.Columns.Add(colId);
        dgv.Columns.Add(colName);
        dgv.Columns.Add(colDescription);
        dgv.Columns.Add(colValues);

        for (int i = 0; i < DataList.Count; ++i)
        {
            MyData dta = DataList[i];
            dgv.Rows.Add(dta.ID, dta.Name, dta.Description);

            if (i % 2 == 1)
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell cmbCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
                string[] arItems = dta.Values.ToArray();
                cmbCell.Items.AddRange(arItems);
                dgv[3, i] = cmbCell;
                if (arItems.Length > 0)
                    cmbCell.Value = arItems[0];
            }
            else
            {
                DataGridViewTextBoxCell txtCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell
                {
                    Value = dta.Values.Count > 0 ? dta.Values[0] : ""
                };
                dgv[3, i] = txtCell;
            }

        }

        dgv.CellEndEdit += Dgv_CellEndEdit;
    }

    private void Dgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    }

    private void PrepareData(int count)
    {
        DataList = new List<MyData>();            

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            DataList.Add(new MyData());
    }
}
```