# Set DataGridViewComboBox default equal to existing DataGridView column

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have added a `DataGridViewComboBox` to a bound `DataGridView` (`grdBOOK`), the `DataGridViewComboBox` will replace column 3 to allow for user selection. I'm struggling to set the default of the `DataGridViewComboBox` equal to the value of column 3 so user selection is not required if the value is correct.

I pulled the code below from the [net](http://mytactics.blogspot.com.au/2014/01/convert-datagridview-column-to-combo-box.html), but I get an error:

> DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

I thought a `ComboBox` cell could be treated as a normal `DataGridView` cell, but (see code below) an error is generated when a string is added to the `ComboBox` column? I've trawled the net and SO for a few days but nothing works, any suggestions please?

```
    public void BOOK_COMBO2()       
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb_cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb_col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

            // Contract field
            cb_col.Items.AddRange("YEARLY", "MONTHLY", "");
            cb_col.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            cb_col.HeaderText = "newCONTRACT";
            cb_col.Width = 50;
            cb_col.ValueType = typeof(string);

            // Add ComboBox and test
            grdBOOK.Columns.Insert(5, cb_col);
            grdBOOK.Rows[14].Cells[4].Value = "zzz";        // No error adding string to normal dgv column
            grdBOOK.Rows[14].Cells[5].Value = "xxx";        // Error adding string to dgvcombobx column

            //copy old values to new combobox and set as default
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in grdBOOK.Rows)
            {
                item.Cells[5].Value = item.Cells[3].Value;      
            }
            //hide original column
            grdBOOK.Columns[3].Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: Where are you calling this `BOOK_COMBO2` method from?

Comment: Also, and more importantly, verify that the values in that column are always one of your options: `"YEARLY", "MONTHLY", ""`. You'll get that error if ever a value is not one of them; and yes, case and whitespace matters - `"Yearly"` and `"  "` will throw the error.

Comment: I call the method from the Main class and the datagridview was added to the main form at design time. I don't get any errors with the list of items, the error is caused by copying values from one of the datagridview columns to the datagridviewcombobox column. This line of code:  ``item.Cells[5].Value = item.Cells[3].Value;  ``

Answer (score 0):

After more research on the net, IMHO using a `ContextMenuStrip` is a better method of achieving this. Link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip(v=vs.110).aspx). A `ContextMenuStrip` has better methods, events, properties etc. I hope this helps others looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender,
            DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            // If the data source raises an exception when a cell value is 
            // commited, display an error message.
            if (e.Exception != null &&
                e.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("");
            }
        }




private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { dataGridView1.DataError +=
                dataGridView1_DataError;}
```